# On a fast high precision numerical analysis C library

Tags: reference-request, na.numerical-analysis, computational-number-theory

This is probably a $y=f(x)$ question, but I searched several times on the MathOverflow without success so I decided to explicitly ask for the help of other members: please feel free to ask me to remove the question if inappropriate.
Nearly a month or so, in a MathOverflow answer (I guess so, but at this point I should consider the possibility I am wrong) to a question on (computational) number theory I read about a C library for arbitrary precision arithmetic which was successfully used in several research papers, including one where the Authors proved the existence of a soliton solution to a PDE by proving the strict positivity of a term by estimating its size as being not less than a $21$ bit mantissa multiplied by $10^{-5000}$ (I am fairly sure of this fact but, as already said, I should consider the possibility I am wrong). I went to the library web page and saved the link in my bookmarks: then a crash occurred (yes, also experienced electronics engineers lose data...) and up until now I was not able to find the former Q&A.

**Question**: can someone provide me a reference to this library?

Comment: Could it be https://gmplib.org/ ?

Comment: @Adrien, unfortunately no. GMP is somewhat standard and I know it from my old days of avid linux user. However thanks a lot.

Comment: Possibly [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/)?

Comment: @J.J.Green neither, I had a look but it seems the library is not it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Does looking at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_arbitrary-precision_arithmetic_software help to remember the library?

Comment: @PeterMueller wow! Thank you very much! I'll swim through the list and then I'll see.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since you speak about mathematical proofs, probably you don't want an arbitrary-precision library, but a verified computation library based on interval arithmetic.

Maybe [Arb](https://arblib.org/)? Or [boost-interval](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/libs/numeric/interval/doc/interval.htm)?

And maybe the post you remembered is about Warwick Tucker [proving](https://mathoverflow.net/a/123683/1898) the existence of the Lorenz attractor.

Comment: Your citation of [Arb](https://arblib.org) was illuminating: following the link I went to [Fredrik Johansson's web page](https://fredrikj.net/) and found [Calcium](https://fredrikj.net/calcium/) and their current bundle [FLINT](https://flintlib.org/applications.html) which was I was searching for. For the post, I was simply fooled as I remembered the [application of FLINT by Joel Dahne and Javier Gómez-Serrano](https://flintlib.org/applications.html). Thank you sooo much, Federico!!